# FireFox looses form data on history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser-cache

We have this online system that creates forms, but we are having a caching issue with FireFox only.

We tested on FireFox 33 & 35 and same thing happens on both.

If you open the form over https://, then fill out some of the fields and let's say you missed one of the required fields. When you click next the _post page validates the data before saving, if there are any errors pops up a javascript alert and then uses history.go(-1) to go back to the previous page so the user can fill the missing field or correct any invalid entry.

On all other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE) when going back, the form data is kept and visible. But on FireFox alone when going back, the data is missing. So if you are filling out a large form is a pain to loose all the data.

Currently using

```
Cache-Control: Private
```

But tried

```
Cache-Control: Public

Cache-Control: no-cache

Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate

Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
```

Both in the HTTP headers and html meta tags, with no luck and we are still loosing all the data.

Is there any way to fix this without installing any extension on the browser ?

Comment: You may want to either validate the data before submitting (or via ajax) or redisplay the form with the post data after validation fails on the server.

Comment: Need a quicker solution than that and that supports classic asp, there is a lot of legacy code involved I'm afraid.